# Can I ignore rows when Loading Data Into a table?

Tags: mysql, xml

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'c:/users/ryan/desktop/2.xml'
REPLACE INTO TABLE product
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>'
```

I want to only update 2 rows based on my XML file. Can I ignore specific rows of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore specified number of first rows, e.g. - 'IGNORE 10 LINES'; otherwise, load all rows into another table, then write UPDATE or INSERT...SELECT query to change rows you need (there should be keys to specify these rows).